# vector iterators incompatible with const vector&

Tags: c++

I'm writing program for graphs. In this program I have a method which has to return vertices inside the weak component originating at vertex. I am getting: Error "vector iterators incompatible"

```
struct graph {
    std::vector <std::vector<int>> gr;
};


std::vector<int> weak_component(const graph& g, int vertex) {
    std::vector<int> ret;
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(vertex);
    vector<int>::iterator j;
    bool* used = new bool[g.gr.size()];
    while (!s.empty()) {
        int hodn=s.top();
        s.pop();
        used[hodn] = true;
        for (j == g.gr[hodn].begin(); j != g.gr[hodn].end(); j++) {
            if (!used[*j]) {
                s.push(*j);
                ret.push_back(*j);
        }
    }
}
    return ret;
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: `j == g.gr[hodn].begin();` should be `j = g.gr[hodn].begin();`.

Comment: @PeteBecker when I delete one of the = it says that no operator "=" matches  these operands.

Comment: In wich line does the error occur? Also, you are leaking memory (you are not deleting `used`)

Comment: That doesn't mean that == is the right behavior. == compares, = assigns. If = doesn't compare it is a sign that something is wrong. And as Ryan already pointed out, your types weren't matching up. Who is freeing the memory of "used"? Consider std::vector<bool>. In 2016, a raw pointer should make you nervous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are taking `g` as a `const graph&`, this means `g.gr` is treated as `const` inside your function.  `begin` on a `const vector<T>` returns a `const_iterator`.  (also you used `==` instead of `=` for assignment)

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator j = g.gr[hodn].begin(); ...)
```

But with C++11 or newer you may as well use `auto` to avoid this

```
for (auto j = g.gr[hodn].begin(); ...)
```

or a range-based for:

```
for (auto&& e : g.gr) {
    if (!used[e]) {
        s.push(e);
        ret.push_back(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: after I edited it it says Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1168 cannot open C:.../DU2.exe for writing DU2 C:..\DU2\LINK 1

Comment: @Lemmy that is a completely different error outside the scope of this question and would need more information to diagnose, including your platform and compiler

Comment: @Lemmy if you are unable to figure it out you'll need to make a new question with the relevant information. I can't begin to guess at your problem based on what you have here, but I also never use visual studio